# Call method every 30 second is not working

Tags: android, service

I want to update user location in every 30 second for which i am using volley request with Service.
The code in bellow:

```
public class CarLocationUpdateService extends Service {


    Context context;
    long delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
    long period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec.

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context = this;


        Handler ha=new Handler();
        ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //call function

                CarLocationUpdateVolleyClass carLocationUpdateVolleyClass=new CarLocationUpdateVolleyClass(context);
                carLocationUpdateVolleyClass.carLocationRequest();

            }
        }, delay);



        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use JobScheduler with firbaseJobDispatcher 
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use fused location service to get location updates.I have created a service to get location updates.This code will give you the location in `onLocationChanged` method.
Check out my answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602323/3789993)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @override 
        public void run() {
            f();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(r, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   final Handler ha=new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ...

            ha.postDelayed(this,30000);
        }
    };
    ha.post(runnable);
```

Comment: 300? That isn't 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the `handler.postDelayed()` method again inside the runnable because it´s executed only once, that´s a normal behaviour. Seperate the runnable from the handler like this:

```
Handler ha = new Handler();

private Runnable yourRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

  CarLocationUpdateVolleyClass carLocationUpdateVolleyClass=new CarLocationUpdateVolleyClass(context);
                carLocationUpdateVolleyClass.carLocationRequest();
     ha.postDelayed(yourRunnable, 30000);
    }
};

ha.post(yourRunnable);
```

by the way, your question tells us something about 30 seconds, but you just call it every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works

```
public void doWork(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // insert your data to db here


                // close this activity
               doWork();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
    }
```

And then simple call this method in `onStartCommand()`

```
doWork();
```