# GoogleApiClient doesn't refresh my location at onChangedLocation method

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location

I would like to update my code by refreshing my location. Currently I a code:

```
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
```

But I'm pretty sure it doesn't refresh my postion. I assume that by driving a car with app running and my position hasn't changed. Please tell me what should I fix to improve it? The thing what I understand that it follows my location is whenever I change my location and will go out of the map, the map will follow me.

Also please tell me if there is a possibility to create kind of icon (**not marker** - that's what I have now (the marker)) which would display my current position?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    private Location location;
    private double lat, lng;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    private List<WashLocation> washLocations;

    private Button favoriteWashesButton;
    private Button isFavorite;
    List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Spinner sItems;
    String choosenDistance;
    private static DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    AlertDialog alert;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LatLng myLocation;
    private Location lastKnownLocation;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LatLng latLng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMapAsync(this);
            if (mMap != null) {
                //setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public LatLng getLatLng() {
        return latLng;
    }

    public void setLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        setLatLng(latLng);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11), 2000, null);

        generateMap(getLatLng(), "3000");

        sItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                washLocations.clear();
                washLocations.size();
                String latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
                String longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);

                generateMap(getLatLng(), null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }


        });
    }


    private String getCity(String s) {
        int i = s.lastIndexOf(',');
        return s.substring(i, s.length());
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fused location service to get location updates. Make a background service and get location every specific interval.Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602323/3789993

Comment: Ok, I will test it. BTW: the map follow you when you change your position?

Comment: It will give you the current location in specific interval of time wherever you go..you have to use that location to display on map

Comment: But if you at my method:
`@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }` there I update the location and pass it to the method which displays map - so please tell me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Look at my method `onLocationChange` which update the location - why it doesn't work? At the link which you posted the body of the method doesn't differ widely